# Django/React: Fetching API endpoint works fine from within the application, but returns 404 when request comes from outside

Tags: reactjs, django

So I made an React + Django app and decided to seperate it, so the backend would work just as a rest API, and frontend would send requests to it. The goal was to facilitate hosting it.

As a single app it works fine. API requests are returned like so `[25/Oct/2022 14:31:21] ←[m"GET /spotify/current-song HTTP/1.1" 200 236←[0m`

But then I seperated the frontend, installed cors headers in django to accept traffic from the react app and most of it works fine.

**However**: the api call to fetch info from spotify API gets a response `[25/Oct/2022 14:31:41] ←[33m"GET /spotify/current-song HTTP/1.1" 404 2←[0m Not Found: /spotify/current-song`, even though this is the very same endpoint that worked when the call came from within the app.

The API call from react app:

```
const getCurrentSong = async () => {
const song = await fetch(`${BASEURL}spotify/current-song`);
if (!song.ok || song.status == 204) {
    return defaultSong;
}
const songJson = await song.json();
setSong(songJson);
document.body.style.backgroundImage = `url('${songJson.image_url}')`;
};

useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        getCurrentSong();
    }, 1000);
    setAppBackground();
    getRoomDetails();

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, []);
```

Django project urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # other, irrelevant
    path('spotify/', include('spotify.urls')),
]
```

And django *spotify* app urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("current-song", CurrentSong.as_view()),
    # other, irrelevant
]
```

I checked and other `spotify/` endpoints are getting called just fine. There are no typos here, so what is the problem?

Comment: might be dumb but maybe try adding a trailing slash inside your `fetch` command in react?

Comment: @rymanso the solution to this problem might be even dumber, but that's not it. other api fetch commands have no trailing slash, neither does this command in the original joint app, and they all work.